# How to import/recreate large number of DDLs from Dev to Prod instance of Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql, database-migration, databricks, ddl

I need to deploy large number of DDLs from Dev into production instance of Databricks. I have the DDLs extracted in a file; is there a way to recreate them in production without running each of them manually?

The DDLs are written on Spark SQL; I tried to google but could not find much! Appreciate your help.

Please Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: where are you maintaining your DDL ? in databricks notebook ?

Answer (score 2):

You could either write a script to execute all DDLs you already have together or you could export them from your source environment:

```
dbs = spark.catalog.listDatabases()
for db in dbs:
  f = open("your_file_name_{}.ddl".format(db.name), "w")
  tables = spark.catalog.listTables(db.name)
  for t in tables:
    DDL = spark.sql("SHOW CREATE TABLE {}.{}".format(db.name, t.name))
    f.write(DDL.first()[0])
    f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

This generates one file with all existing DDLs in all database which you can use to recreate them into the target.